# hashchange in jquery?

Tags: jquery

Im using the following example for hash change:

```
$(window).trigger('hashchange');

$('.navBtn').bind('hashchange',function(){ 
    var hval = location.hash.slice(1); // remove the leading #
    alert(hval);
});
```

But nothing appears to happen, I get no alert. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need

```
//the js
$(window).bind('hashchange',function(){ 
    var hval = location.hash.slice(1); // remove the leading #
    alert(hval);
}); 

<!--the html-->
<a href="#imTheHash">Click me</a>
```

The hash change event is fired on the window. There is no js needed to change the hash. this is handled be the browser. ie clicking on the link will change the hash and the window event 'hashchange' will then be fired.

Answer (score 1):

You're triggering the event before binding your handler. Invert the order and try again?

Also, I'm not sure, but you're triggering the event on the window element, but binding it on a set of sub elements. I don't know how that will work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to:

1. Inverse the order: bind then trigger
2. use the same selector

   ```
   $(window).bind('hashchange',function(){ 
     var hval = location.hash.slice(1); // remove the leading #
     alert(hval);
   }); 
   $(window).trigger('hashchange');
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Hashchange happens on the `window` object. What do you intend for `$('.navBtn').bind('hashchange', ...)` to mean?

Comment: when you click on a nav button it'll load the url a href"/something#home" and then the jquery will get the hash

Comment: Your nav button should only set the hash, i.e. `href="#home"`, and then `hashchange` will occur on `window`. You should be listening to hashchange events on the window object.